# Express session can't get stored session values for next request

Tags: node.js, session, express, express-session

I'm trying to learn how express session is used. I wrote the following code. When I visit the **/session** route from Postman, every time it shows following in console:

**not set**

**vikaskumar**

What I expect is **vikaskumar** only, after first request. I guess it is saving this string in session but not storing in memory store. But as per docs, the memory store is default, so it should save it automatically?

Here's the code:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var views = req.session.username;

    if (!views) {
        console.log("not set");
        req.session.username = 'vikaskumar';
    }

    next();
});

app.get("/session", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.session.username);
    res.write(req.session.username);
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: is `usernmae` intentional or a typo?

Comment: you have to use Postman Interceptor to work with cookies in Postman, that's why it's not setting the session.

Comment: If I visit from browser? @tbking

Comment: Then it should be ok. What do you see in that case?

Comment: Well it's working. Could you please answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44608114/whats-the-difference-between-reconnectionattempts-and-pingtimeout

Comment: Glad it helped. Can you mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to use [Postman Interceptor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en) for cookies to work with Postman.

Comment: which answer are you talking about? And what's properly?

Comment: The question about pingTimeout on my another account.

Comment: It's not related to this question

Comment: see this: It's still not working even when tried with browser. It works only for GET requests: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712538/cant-save-express-session-in-nodejs