# Can't save express session in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, session, express, express-session

I'm trying to save the userName of a user in express session. It saves the variable in session but it returns `undefined` on next request to the route. However, the problem is with POST route only.

With GET request, I can save session variable and it doesn't get destroyed on further requests. I think I must be doing something wrong. I tried `save()` method for POST but still it saves only first time and next time it is vanished.

Here's the code:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'some secret',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 36000000,
    httpOnly: false
  },
}));
```

FOLLOWING GET ROUTE WORKS.

```
app.get("/test", function(req, res, next){
    if(!req.session.name){
        req.session.name = "vikas kumar";
    } else {
        console.log(req.session.name);
    }
    res.end();
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var userName = req.session.userName;
  // console.log(req.session.userName);
  if(userName && userName != 'undefined'){
    res.send({status: "success", value: userName});
  } else {
    if(req.path == '/checkIfLoggedIn'){
        res.send({status: "error", message: "Session ended."});
    } else {
        next('route');
    }
  }
});
```

FOLLOWING ROUTE SAVES SESSION ONLY ONCE.

```
app.post('/getProfile', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("Session", req.session.userName, req.session.name);
    if(typeof req.session.userName != 'undefined'){
        var userName = req.session.userName;
    } else {
        var userName = req.body.userName;
    }
   connectionPool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({status: "error", message: err});
        } else {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM cs_chat.users WHERE username=?", [userName], function (err, rows, fields) {
            if(rows.length==1){
                // console.log(">>>", req.session.userName);
                req.session.userName = userName;
                req.session.save();
                // console.log("<<<", req.session.userName);
                next();
            }else{
                res.send({status: "error", message: "Sorry, you're not registered."});
            }
            connection.release();

        });

        }
    });
}, function (req, res) {
    connectionPool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({status: "error", message: err});
        } else {
            req.session.username = req.body.userName;
            req.session.save();
        connection.query("SELECT usr.username, usr.name, tsn.sender, CASE WHEN tsn.unseen is not null THEN tsn.unseen ELSE 0 END as unseen, tsn.receiver FROM users usr LEFT JOIN (SELECT sender, receiver, SUM(CASE WHEN seen = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unseen FROM messages WHERE receiver = ? GROUP BY sender , receiver) tsn ON usr.username = tsn.sender where usr.username!=?", [req.body.userName, req.body.userName], function (err, rows, fields) {
            if(rows.length>0){
                res.send({status: "success", values: rows});
            }else{
                res.send({status: "success", values: []});
            }
            connection.release();
        });

        }
    });
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: well in your `POST` request you are not saving the session so that, form it later the username can be retrieved from it later in your other restricted routes. See this similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26531143/3521116)

Comment: But I've already written `save()` method?

Comment: First of all can you please tell me why are you using two `function` when you can do the above in single function only, connecting to `connectionPool` will simply increase the response time of the server and in the first `function(req, res, next)` why are you using the `next()` it's not required.

Comment: and since it's javascript you are checking equality with `==` instead you should be checking it with `===` this might be one of the reasons. like `if(rows.length==1)` should be `if(rows.length===1)`

Answer (score 0):

Since it is `Javascript` you should be checking quality with `===` instead of `==` and for better response time releasing the connection and then again connecting to it, is simply unnecessary, when you have the connection to `connectionPool` just query from it twice and then release the connection.

Here is the sample modified `app.post()..` request, this should work:

```
    app.post('/getProfile', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("Session", req.session.userName, req.session.name);
    var userName = (req.session.userName !== undefined) ? req.session.userName : req.body.userName;

    connectionPool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({ status: "error", message: err });
        } else {
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM cs_chat.users WHERE username=?", [userName], function (err, rows, fields) {
                if (rows.length === 1) {
                    req.session.userName = userName;
                    req.session.save();
                } else {
                    res.send({ status: "error", message: "Sorry, you're not registered." });
                }
            });
            connection.query("SELECT usr.username, usr.name, tsn.sender, CASE WHEN tsn.unseen is not null THEN tsn.unseen ELSE 0 END as unseen, tsn.receiver FROM users usr LEFT JOIN (SELECT sender, receiver, SUM(CASE WHEN seen = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unseen FROM messages WHERE receiver = ? GROUP BY sender , receiver) tsn ON usr.username = tsn.sender where usr.username!=?",
                [req.body.userName, req.body.userName],
                function (err, rows, fields) {
                    if (rows.length > 0) {
                        res.send({ status: "success", values: rows });
                    } else {
                        res.send({ status: "success", values: [] });
                    }
                });
            connection.release();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: not sure if it will completely solve the problem, but this is one of the problem for sure

Comment: While  the post request can you see the  `req.session.userName` in your console output ?

Comment: Leave the post, actually it's not even working for the GET request. I've explained my problem here again. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745218/express-session-with-express-mysql-session-not-working-at-all